# Service or Activity?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

I'm struggling to decide which class to use, Activity or Service.
My application is complicated so I will use another example. A timer.

I would like to create an application that start to count the seconds when I open the application and keep counting even when I click the back button.
When I back to the application it will have a gui that show me the time.

So the gui I guess would be the activity and the counting method would be on the service.. but how do I manage that system?how they will be communicating? how can I do that?

Comment: If that is all you need to do then you could simply have the `Activity` that shows you the time. When you get out of the activity simply save the time at that moment in the preferences. When you come back, compute the passed time from that save time and show it.

Comment: That's a solution but you are missing the point which is keep running the application in the backrgound

Comment: "That's a solution but you are missing the point which is keep running the application in the backrgound" -- then come up with a better fake scenario than this. You need nothing running in the background to be able to keep track of running time.

Comment: As I said, it's just an exmaple the timer. I'm looking for a communication between service and an activity.

Comment: There are many ways to perform "communication between service and an activity". Which one(s) are best for a given situation are very dependent *upon that situation*. The right one for the timer situation is to not write a service in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BroadcastReceivers and send broadcasts that your activity will be listening to, or you can use Messenger to send messages from the service to the activity

Comment: and if the activity should just stop/start the service? those options are still preferred?

Comment: I believe so, because lets say the activity stoped the service, no broadcasts or messages will be sent and received

Comment: I'm not familiar with those classes so I'm preferring right now to just stop the service by a piece of code, something like server.stop() is it possible?

Comment: here is a link to read about BroadcastReceivers in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html , and here is a link for services and it will tell you how to stop a service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

they can communicate with intents, or via shared storage, or content providers, ...

Comment: Why does they have to send intents?the only thing they both care about is the time value. shouldn't be just an int? but how?

Comment: because of the lifecycle of both the activity and the service. You can do a very ugly trick of setting an static field in one of the classes and accessing it from both, but I only mention it for you to know that is technically possible, is it by no means the way you should do it.